# Java - Call method on a subclass (Process 'user code' before finishing method)?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, super

I've got a base class called GameEngine, which is supposed to be the "core" of my "game engine". It does all the graphics processing and physics ticks. However, I don't want to put my actual source code for the game in this class. So this is essentially what I have:

```
//GameEngine
void start() {
    //While loop to call render() and tick()
}
void render() {
    //BufferStrategy, etc.
    //[[[[HERE]]]] Call method on subclass
    //dispose() and show()
}
void tick() { }
```

and...

```
//SampleGame
public class SampleGame extends GameEngine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameEngine().start();
    }
    public void render() {
        //This gets called before dispose() and show()
    }

}
```

So, how can I get the render() method to be called in the subclass by the superclass? I cannot override the superclass method because it needs to do some work before and after the subclass's render() method is called.

Thank you

Comment: Why is it a subclass at all? Is there other code that the two share a lot of? You won't be able to call the subclass's method without making an instance of it in the superclass.

Comment: You basic understanding of OOP, inheritance and classes seems lacking. You should *probably* study

Comment: I thought initially to write an answer, but this Wiki link answers your question perfectly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern#Example_in_Java

Comment: Thanks, @Amit, I probably should, however, I don't have much need for Java as applets are going to die in a few years. It would still be helpful. I have a fine understanding of inheritance in other languages, but this question was just a strange case. Thank you for your concern

Comment: OK, I'm sorry for "misreading" your knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Declare `render()` as an `abstract` method in the superclass, which it invokes at the appropriate point. The subclass then defines the behavior of this method by overriding it with a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the 'slot method design pattern'. In short, you have a final sequence of steps of an alorithm but need to allow parameterizing it at specific steps. These specific steps are where 'slot methods' would be called.
Typically, slot methods are protected (abstract) methods prefixed with doXXX().

Example:

```
//GameEngine
void start() {
    //While loop to call render() and tick()
}
void render() {
    //BufferStrategy, etc.
    doCallUserCode();
    //dispose() and show()
}
void tick() { }
protected abstract doCallUserCode();
```